# append html text from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a JavaScript function that takes Id and source and alignment... and append to html element due to the input parameter.

```
"<TR id='" + localMessageId + "' onmouseover='visiblepointmenu(\"" + localMessageId + "\");' onmouseout='hidepointmenu(\"" + localMessageId + "\");'>" +
  "<TD class='td_left noselect' nowrap='nowrap' align='right'>" + Image + "</td>" +
  "<TD class='td_center' style='table-layout:fixed; direction: " + direction + ";'>" +
    "<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>" +
      "<TR style='HEIGHT:10px; " + VisibleHiddenTime + "'>" +
        "<TD><div class='noselect' style='color:DarkGray;text-align:" + float_Timer + ";font-size: 11px;'>" + Name + dateMessage.ToString("hh:mm tt") + "</div></TD>" +
      "</TR > " +
      "<TR>" +
        "<TD id = 'menu" + localMessageId + "' oncontextmenu='window.external.Menu(\"pointMenu#3\",\"" + message + "\", \"" + localMessageId + "\");'>" +
          "<TABLE  cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 style='background-image: url(data:image/png;base64," + previewLink.image_Base64 + ");" +
          "background-position: center center;width:" + previewLink.width.ToString() + "px;height:" + previewLink.height.ToString() + "px; background-repeat: no-repeat; " +
          "background-size: 100% 100%; float:" + float_Timer + ";'>" +
          "<TBODY>" +
            "<TR style='height: 83%;'>" +
              "<TD class='description' onclick=openURL('" + url + "')  style='cursor:pointer;padding-left:10px;' valign='bottom' align='left'>" +
              "<font color='white' style='font-size: 110%'> " + previewLink.description + "</font>" +
              "</TD>" +
            "</TR>" +
            "<TR style='vertical-align:top;'>" +
              "<TD align='left' onclick=openURL('" + url + "') style='cursor:pointer; padding-left:10px;' >" +
              "<font color='white' style='font-size: 100%' >" + homelink + "</font>" +
              "</TD>" +
            "</TR>" +
          "</TBODY>" +
          "</TABLE>" +
        "</TD>" +
        "<TD style='vertical-align:top;'>" +
          "<div style='float:" + afloat + ";'>" +
            "<img id='pnt" + localMessageId + "' class='noselect' draggable='false' src='data:image/png;base64," + SharedData.PointMenu + "' style='visibility:hidden;display:none;' onclick='window.external.Menu(\"pointMenu#3\", \"" + message + "\", \"" + localMessageId + "\");' />" +
          "</div>" +
        "</TD>" +
      "</TR>" +
    "</TABLE>" +
  "</TD>" +
  "<TD style='width:17px;' valign='top' align='left'>" +
    "<img style='margin-top: 3px;" + visibility + "' id='read" + localMessageId + "' draggable='false' class='noselect' src='data:image/png;base64," + SharedData.getMessageStatusFromEnum(messageStatus, SendingMethode == SharedData.NotificationSendingMethod.AutoReply) + "'/>" +
  "</TD>" +
"</TR>";
}
else
{
  new_row = "<TR id='" + localMessageId + "' onmouseover='visiblepointmenu(\"" + localMessageId + "\");' onmouseout='hidepointmenu(\"" + localMessageId + "\");'>" +
    "<TD class='td_left noselect' nowrap='nowrap' align='right'>" + Image + "</td>" +
    "<TD class='td_center' id='Forward" + localMessageId + "' style='table-layout:fixed;direction:" + direction + ";'>" +
      "<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>" +
        "<TR style='HEIGHT:10px; " + VisibleHiddenTime + "'>" +
          "<TD><div class='noselect' style='color:DarkGray;text-align:" + float_Timer + "; font-size: 11px;'>" + Name + dateMessage.ToString("hh:mm tt") + "</div></TD>" +
        "</TR>" +
        "<TR>" +
          "<TD id ='link" + localMessageId + "'>" +
            "<div id='menu" + localMessageId + "' class='" + classname + "' oncontextmenu='window.external.Menu(\"pointMenu#3\",\"" + message + "\", \"" + localMessageId + "\");'>" +
              "   <P style='table-layout:fixed;'>" + text + "</p>" +
            "</div>" +
          "</TD>" +
          "<TD style='vertical-align:top;'>" +
            "<DIV style='float:" + afloat + ";'>" +
              "<img id='pnt" + localMessageId + "' class='noselect' draggable='false' src='data:image/png;base64," + SharedData.PointMenu + "' style='visibility:hidden;display:none;');' onclick='window.external.Menu(\"pointMenu#3\", \"" + message + "\", \"" + localMessageId + "\");' />" +
            "</DIV>" +
          "</TD>" +
        "</TR>" +
      "</TABLE>" +
    "</TD>" +
    "<TD style='width:17px;' valign='top' align='left'>" +
      "<img style='margin-top: 3px;" + visibility + "' id='read" + localMessageId + "' draggable='false' class='noselect' src='data:image/png;base64," + SharedData.getMessageStatusFromEnum(messageStatus, SendingMethode == SharedData.NotificationSendingMethod.AutoReply) + "'/>" +
    "</TD>" +
  "</TR>"
```

my problem is that id and all image sources and even some classes should be added at runtime from the function
I need a way better then concatenation because my code will be ugly if I type + every time
or want to know what is the best Practice

Comment: You can use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for multiline strings. Apart from that, you could include both html parts in your page and with CSS add `display: none` if it shouldn't be visible. Seems cleaner to me. Or use a framework like Angular/React/...

Comment: I use it in WebView 2 C# control, so I am so limited to use a framework @A_A

Comment: For a line of two of js, template literal (as noted above).  For the amount of html you have: pre-rendered html in the page that you .clone() then update.   Will just be that much easier to maintain with an HTML editor.  Depending on where you get your data: if it's an ajax call, you could return server-rendered html